# Having two mysql queries in a statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to put two queries in a mysql statement. This query works when I simulate it in mysql but when I try it on the page it does not work. Is there anything wrong with it?

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id='$id' AND user_id='$user_id';
        DELETE FROM tbl_collab WHERE tbl_upload_id='$id'";
```

Comment: Note that shouldn't put variables directly into SQL string. Use prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `mysqli_query()` can run only a single query. Therefore you have to run these two queries separately.